# como Introducir una Multiplicacion en PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel

si alguie me pudiese ayuudar necesito introducir desde PHPExcel una formula para multiplicar cantidades por montos, sin tener que registrarlo en la base de datos ni colapsar el sistema de ciclos

Comment: Por favor considera leer [ask]

Answer (score 0):

te pongo este ejemplo, espero que te sirva

```
// Creamos el objeto
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Inicializamos variables
$totalProductos = 1; // Comienza en 1 por el encabezado
$precioCaramelos = 3;
$precioChicles = 6;

// Definimos encabezados
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Cantidad');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Producto');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'Precio "unitario"');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'Importe');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2', 8);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B2', 'Caramelo');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C2', $precioCaramelos);
$totalProductos++;

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A3', 5);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B3', 'Chicle');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C3', $precioChicles);
$totalProductos++;

// Sumamos 1 a $totalProductos por el encabezado
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C'.($totalProductos+1), 'Total');

// Realizamos las operaciones necesarias
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D2', '=A2*C2');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D3', '=A3*C3');

// Calculamos el gran total
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D'.($totalProductos+1), '=D2*D3');
```

Comment: creo que mi problema ya no es con la logica sino con phpexcel, porque me sale este error <b>Notice</b>:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Cerberos\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php</b> on line <b>1117</b><br />